# Is there any way to use weekview in Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, calendar

I want to use week view with Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar.
Is there any way to use week view with using Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar

Comment: I dont know whether it is possible using xamarin.plugin.calander. If you want week view only https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126791/how-to-design-the-week-view-calender-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use 
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/calendar/display-modes#week-view
Syncfusion one is free if you qualify for the community license.